# Google maps api Circle gradient?

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am adding circle overlays to my map.  I can now properly set the color, opacity etc.  How would I achieve a color gradient (i.e. radially out from the center)? Is this even possible?

(I am using api v3, but if you have a solution with v2 I would love to see it too).